# Skorohod representation theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Assume $X_n$ are random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_n \leq B)=1$ for some random variable $B$. Assume also $X_n \Rightarrow X$ ($X_n$ converges weakly to $X$). By the skorohod representation theorem, there exists another probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}')$ and random variables $X_n'$, $X'$ on it (equal in distribution to the $X_n$'s, $X$) such that $X_n' \to X'$ almost everwhere. My question is: can I find a random variable $B'$ equal in distribution to $B$ such that $\mathbb{P}'(X_n' \leq B')=1$.

My problem is the following : if it was true that $(X_n,B) \Rightarrow (X^*,B^*)$ with $X^*=X$ in distribution and $B^*=B$ in distribution, then the result would be proved by the Skorohod representation theorem. But it's not true in general, right?

It's OK I found the answer: the sequence $(X_n,B)$ is tight. Take a converging subsequence $n_k$ such that $(X_{n_k},B) \Rightarrow (X^*,B^*)$. Then it implies $X^*=X$ and $B^*=B$ in distrib. Then apply the Skorohod repr. thm:  there exists another probability space $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',\mathbb{P}')$ and random variables $X_{n_k}',B'$, $X_*'$, $B_*'$ on it (equal in distribution to the $X_{n_k}$'s, $X$,$B^*$,$X^*$) such that $(X_{n_k}',B') \to (X_*', B_*')$ almost everwhere. In particular $\mathbb{P}'(X_{n_k}' \leq B')=1$.

Comment: Post an answer.